# Bootstrap Sass broke devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, devise

Hi I hope someone can help. I i'm building a news application on rails. I installed devise and act-as-votable for posts. I then installed bootstrap-sass (twbs/bootstrap-sass) and devise wont render to the screen.

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>       
    <div class="index_log">
      Hey, your logged in as <strong><%= current_user.email %></strong>.
  <% if user_signed_in? %>     
        <%= button_to "Log Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-default navbar-btn' %>
  <% else %>
    <%= link_to "Log In", new_user_session_path, class: 'btn btn-default navbar-btn', method: :get %>
  <% end %>
```

When I go go to the login page, enter my username and password, nothing happens.
Or else I create a new user, again nothing happens.
Any Ideas - I would add code below but I'm not sure what to add.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have an extra `if user_signed_in?` tag

```
Hey, your logged in as <strong><%= current_user.email %></strong>.
<% if user_signed_in? %>
```

and that is messing up your `<% else %>` (which now matches the extra `if` and is now nested within the first `if user_signed_in?` and will never be rendered.

Also, unrelated, but it should be "...you're logged in as..." and the `div class="index_log"` isn't closed

Comment: Great, how did I not notice that, I have been looking at it for the last 2 days. Any Idea about the other Issue above? Thanks a million.

Comment: Apologies - I though I was doing the right thing. I seem to get voted down for not changing the question after it is answered.